# Does Windows needs its own boot partition when dual booting?

Tags: windows-7, linux, windows, boot, multi-boot

My laptop comes with Windows 7. There was 100MB NTFS partition. I decided to remove it and use it as a `/boot` partition. After installing Archlinux and Syslinux, Windows didn't boot from syslinux. It is visible but nothing happens when choosing Windows option from bootloader menu. Disk and partition in syslinux.cfg seems OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows doesn't need a boot partition. All can be contained within a single volume. In fact you can't mount most of Windows' folders on various partitions like Linux. On the root of that volume there will be some files needed for Windows start up: the bootloader (`bootmgr`) and BCD entries for the boot menu options.

However since Vista, by default it'll create a small NTFS partition around 100-500MB to store those boot and recovery files when you create the Windows partition. That's to avoid the trouble when you need to use BitLocker or dynamic disks, as boot loader can't be on an encrypted partition or a dynamic volume. If you delete that boot partition, there's no more boot manager, no boot loader, which definitely makes Windows unbootable

Inserting Windows installation disk and select ***repair*** might solve the problem, but not always, because you might have changed the partition number and/or drive letter and some programs won't work any more